# Add Zendesk API library to Magento 1.x Enterprise?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, zendesk

I'm trying to add the Zendesk API library to Magento 1.x Enterprise. The default Zendesk extension for Magento does not have the functionalities that I need. It doesn't seem to contain the functions to create new tickets from custom web form.

I have installed the offical Zendesk API PHP library from here: https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php

And installed it in Magento's lib folder. However, when I attempt to include the library in other files, it throws an error saying the class is not found. I believe this is due to the library does not follow the Zend naming conventions.

Any ideas on how to use libraries that do not follow the Zend naming convention in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it uses namespacing which Magento 1.x doesn't support with its *own* autoloader.

You can still use it though, you just can't rely on it to be loaded with Magento's autoloader. The easiest way would probably be to [install it with composer](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php#composer), then include it using composer's autoloader, for example:

```
# File: app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Helper/Data.php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; # get composer's autoloader
class YourCompany_YourModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getZenDesk()
    {
        $client = new \Zendesk\API\HttpClient($subdomain, $username);
        // do stuff with it
    }
}
```

If it doesn't find `vendor/autoload.php` automatically you may need to be more specific, i.e.:

```
require_once Mage::getBaseDir('base') . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```